# Scrollbar not displaying on opening softkeyboard

Tags: android, scrollbar, scrollview, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

My fragment consists of ScrollView.Initially the content of fragment is able to fit in screen so there is no need of scrollbar.But when i open softkeyboard half the content is hidden behind keyboard so i want that scrollbar should be displayed.But it is not displaying.I tried putting below line in manifest but same result-

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
   >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/post_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone">
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ns"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="News Source Link*"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittextbordergrey"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/cwTextPrimaryColor"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/actiontext"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/autofill_text_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/ns"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Auto fill"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/username" />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/headline_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Headline that explains the real story*"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittextbordergrey"
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_below="@+id/autofill_text_count"
                        android:textColor="@color/cwTextPrimaryColor"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/actiontext"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:maxLines="4"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                        android:maxLength="99" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/headline_text_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/headline_edit_text"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="99 characters"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/cwAccentColor" />
                    <RegularEditText
                        android:id="@+id/source_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Source*"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittextbordergrey"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textColor="@color/cwTextPrimaryColor"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/headline_text_count"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/actiontext"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:maxLength="25" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/source_text_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/source_edit_text"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="25 characters"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/cwAccentColor" />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/news_image_link_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittextbordergrey"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Link to picture or upload below"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/source_text_count"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/cwTextPrimaryColor"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/actiontext"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/top10s_layout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/top10s_headline_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittextbordergrey"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/top10s_headline_default"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="Top 10 "
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/cwTextPrimaryColor" />
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/top10s_headline_edit_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="15dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/cwTextPrimaryColor"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/actiontext"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:maxLength="93" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/top10s_headline_text_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/top10s_headline_layout"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="93 characters"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/cwAccentColor" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/infoText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/top10s_image_link_edit_text"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:text="Be sure to add an image before hitting &#34;Post&#34;"/>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/top10s_image_link_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Link to picture or upload below*"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittextbordergrey"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textColor="@color/cwTextPrimaryColor"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/top10s_headline_text_count"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/actiontext"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/openhumor_layout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone">
                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/openhumor_funny_edit_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="15dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittextbordergrey"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/cwTextPrimaryColor"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/actiontext"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:maxLength="93" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/openhumor_funny_edit_text_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/openhumor_funny_edit_text"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="93 characters"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/cwAccentColor" />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/openhumor_image_link_edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Link to picture or upload below*"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittextbordergrey"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textColor="@color/cwTextPrimaryColor"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/openhumor_funny_edit_text_count"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/actiontext"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/post_layout"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/upload_image"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/camera_icon"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/post_button"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/upload_image_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/upload_image"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
                <TextButton
                    android:id="@+id/post_button"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/cancel_button_bg"
                    android:text="Post"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/preview_imageview"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/post_layout"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/preview_imageview_delete"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/post_layout"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/preview_imageview"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/preview_imageview"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/preview_image_delete"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/empty_action"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/loading_view_progress_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/loading_view_progress_size"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/loading_view_margin_right"
        style="?android:progressBarStyle"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you put layout weight to 1.0 to scrollview  and try. If not working please share your code here.

Comment: @ShaluTD not working..sharing code..

Comment: @ShaluTD code shared..in one device scrollview is appearing but still half content remains hidden behind softkeyboard as screen doesn't adjust..